# Type checking undefined in jQuery style guide

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery has a style guide here: http://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/#type-checks

Type checking `undefined` varies with scope:

**undefined:**

- Global Variables: typeof variable === "undefined"
- Local Variables:  variable === undefined

Why is it necessary and/or preferred to vary this type check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a global variable hasn't been declared, doing `variable === undefined` would throw an error ("variable is not defined"). With local variables you know that they're declared so you don't need to take that possibility into account.

Answer (score 2):

`typeof x` can not throw ReferenceError if there is no variable called `x`.
If you try to `typeof Boolaen === 'undefined'` (typo is intentional) it will return `true`, if you try `Boolaen === undefined` it will throw.
You can check it in your browsers console.

Further reference: [ES 5.1, 11.4.3 - typeof operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3)